# Independent HTML5 Physics Game: Any Feedback?

Tags: game-design, physics, javascript, html5

I've been independently developing a physics-based HTML5 game. I haven't used any libraries or engines; all the code, including the physics, is my own. It is free for a while on the Chrome Web Store and I was hoping that I could get some feedback on it. You can get it for Chrome here: [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dbnmkpcomailjochphnmfklofkmgenci](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dbnmkpcomailjochphnmfklofkmgenci/reviews).
 I know this is not a normal question, but I'm happy for answers to be abstracted/generalized for broader use. Im asking here because I don't know anyone else personally who does this stuff. Any thoughts, comments or ideas you might have would be greatly appreciated!

The physics system is written in JavaScript and works by setting up the differential equations of motion (plus a few conditions) and evaluating them numerically using the Euler method. The graphics are done through the HTML5 canvas and the music is done through the audio element. (Said music is in the public domain by the way). You can see the code by going to VIew>View Source in Chrome.

Comment: This doesn't belong here, and will be closed. You'll have more luck using the chat, or finding a forum related to game development. :)

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager That's fine. It was worth a try, though. Out of curiosity, though, you said I should find a forum related to game development--isn't that the title of this site? Thanks! :)

Comment: This is a **Q&A** site for game development, not a forum. Forums are designed to facilitate discussion, this site is designed so people can find an answer to their questions. There might be some superficial similarities, but forums & this site come with a very different set of tools. Discussions get closed here since they don't really work out well considering the way the site works, and there's already a better tool for those - forums, like gamedev.net's! Welcome to Stack Exchange, by the way!